How to identify which request triggered which response?
I created two functions for the mitmdump addon:
def request(flow)
    pass

def response(flow):
    pass

Since both of these functions are separate and run independently, how can I figure out which request flow caused the response flow?

The methods for request and response are split as they are called at different times.
Looking at the Mitmproxy API documentation you can see that the flow argument of response(flow) function is of type mitmproxy.http.HTTPFlow and each HTTPFlow instance has a request and response property.
If request(flow) is called of course the response property is None as there is not yet a response.
When response(flow) is called you have both the request and it's corresponding response together in the flow argument.
